# Outlook 2010 Group folders within "Favorite Folders"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 is there a way to group two Inbox's into a single Inbox within the "Favorite Folders" section?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have two solutions,(1) using the outlook rules wizard to copy or move the messages from all the inboxes into a single folder, or (2) you can set up the accounts to use the same inbox.